# CRSM did not work for data with score ranged from 0 to 100

Tags: r

Hello right now I'm doing some research and analyzing my data using R, I have stumbled on some error that I cannot solve. My data comprises of continuous item responses ranging from 0 to 100. Here's the example of my Data:

[image: Data Table]

So I've tried to use the pcIRT package and CRSM package to do the analysis for continuous data ranged from 1-100.
I have downloaded and check that the packages needed are active, but this information showed up at the console:

> CRSM (IK_1, 0, 100, 0, conv = 1e-04)
> Error in CRSM(IK_1, 0, 100, 0, conv = 1e-04) :
> could not find function "CRSM"

Are there any steps that I may have missed? Or what should I do when facing this kind of error?

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Did you load the packages with `library(pclRT)` and `library(CRSM)`?

Comment: Me and my colleagues could not find CRSM packages. Is it because I'm using R version 4.0.0 while pcIRT package was developed under R version 4.0.2? Thank you

Comment: Seems like crsm is a function in the pclRT package?

Comment: Yes, it is. CRSM is part of the pcIRT package to compute continuous rating data, specifically. The problem is that the said CRSM can't be run with the situation I found described in the question. I hope there's a way to find any solution to run the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the newest version on cran does not include the `CRSM` function. Installing an older version works (from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/pcIRT/)):

```
# install remotes 
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_version("pcIRT", version = "0.2.3", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
pcIRT::CRSM # now exists
```